# Using a category to override NSURL method

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurl, objective-c-category

Categories question:

I'd like to place a category on NSURL that, among doing other things, overrides the query method to be able to provide a query string from a URL that is not RFC 1808 compliant. Is it legal to do something like this in my category:

```
- (NSString *)query //real NSURL method
{
     if (stringIsRFC1808) //want to get the default implementation
          return [super query];
     else 
          return somethingElse; //want to get my custom implementation
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code as-is is not valid, because you're using `[super query]` - that doesn't quite do what you expect it to do so. Categories aren't superclasses. Here `[super query]` will try to invoke `- [NSObject query]` - BOOM an unrecognized selector error. If you're using categories to extend a class, you won't be able to call the original method - if you don't need this functionality, then using categories is fine, if you do need it, however, you should consider subclassing, (even better composition for Foundation objets!) or using the Objective-C runtime to perform [method swizzling](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1482839994/method-swizzling) - this way you'll have access to the original implementation of the method.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote? Are your serially downvoting me?

Comment: @H2C03 looks like someone doesn't like you today.

Comment: @FilipRadelic yes, for me too... I flagged my amswers for mod attention anyways. Also thanks for those who compensated it.

Comment: +1 IMO SO should make it a must to comment when down voting and even better let users decide if the down vote is justified and cancel it if its not

Answer (score 2):

You should not use categories to override existing methods. 
Categories are used to **enhance** class behavior without sub classing it. (Although I think you could override it is strongly discouraged by Apple)

Answer (score 2):

Add your own method, to not conflict with the apple sdk. Consider someone in your company using this category: The first thing he does is looking into the developer libraries to know, what this method does.

After importing your category, it doesn't do what it should do anymore. Apple doesn't recommend this!